# Git commit machine details

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Is it possible to get the the below details of commits in Git.

1. Machine/Computer name used to commit ?
2. IP address of the computer used ?

I know we can get commit details using `git log` which provides Author Name and Date of commit etc.

Do organizations like github/bitbucket store such information of the public repositories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you set up something like a commit hook that puts that information as part of the commit message.

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0, Do you happen to know if github or bitbucket store such information of the public repositories ?

Comment: They _might_ on the revisions you ask them to create on their side.... but I wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: They surely don't.

Answer (score 1):

No, Neither GitHub nor Bitbucket or any other well established organization would do this. Public IP addresses and Machine Details are relatively sensitive information regarding the user. It is not a good idea to expose this on a public platform.